# AuthorizationCreate in Swift (Xcode 6)

Tags: macos, swift, authorization, xcode6

I've been looking for some help in creating authorization for my app to have it run a few shell scripts as root. I've looked through the Apple documentation (which is of course written in OBJ-C and quite vague) and I'm trying to use the code examples in Swift.

Immediately I'm running in an error with the `AuthorizationCreate` function:

```
    var authRef: AuthorizationRef
    let osStatus = AuthorizationCreate(nil, nil, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authRef)
```

`'Int' is not convertible to 'AuthorizationFlags'`

I'm just trying to follow along with the code snippets in the docs from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-TP9

And I found the constant for `kAuthorizationFlagDefaults` from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Authorization_Options

I'm running in 10.10.1 if that matters.

I've seen the solution for using AppleScript, but I really want to avoid this is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`kAuthorizationFlagDefaults` is an `Int` and has to be converted to 
`AuthorizationFlags` (which is a type alias for `UInt32`). Also `authRef` has to be initialized:

```
var authRef: AuthorizationRef = nil
let authFlags = AuthorizationFlags(kAuthorizationFlagDefaults)
let osStatus = AuthorizationCreate(nil, nil, authFlags, &authRef)
```

Extended example (untested!):

```
var myItems = [
    AuthorizationItem(name: "com.myOrganization.myProduct.myRight1",
        valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0),
    AuthorizationItem(name: "com.myOrganization.myProduct.myRight2",
        valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
]

var myRights = AuthorizationRights(count: UInt32(myItems.count), items: &myItems)

let myFlags = AuthorizationFlags(kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
                kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
                kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights)


var authRef: AuthorizationRef = nil
let authFlags = AuthorizationFlags(kAuthorizationFlagDefaults)
let osStatus = AuthorizationCreate(&myRights, nil, authFlags, &authRef)
```

**Edit: Swift 3**

```
var myItems = [
        AuthorizationItem(name: "com.myOrganization.myProduct.myRight1",
                          valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0),
        AuthorizationItem(name: "com.myOrganization.myProduct.myRight2",
                          valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
    ]

    var myRights = AuthorizationRights(count: UInt32(myItems.count), items: &myItems)

    let myFlags : AuthorizationFlags = [.interactionAllowed, .extendRights]


    var authRef: AuthorizationRef?
    let osStatus = AuthorizationCreate(&myRights, nil, myFlags, &authRef)
```

Comment: @Andrew: I have added more sample code. Please note that I have only verified that it *compiles*, I did not test if it works. I hope that this gets you started.

Comment: This is great!! I was able to get everything to compile appropriately. Checking the value of osStatus returns 0. Now the last question, how can i use this with NSTask. I'm not sure If I'm doing this right, but I'm hoping to get a shell script launched from my app bundle with root privileges.

Comment: @Andrew: I am sorry, that's all I have. But have a look at Apple's demo project https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html, that might help.

Comment: This is great!! Working on my project.